# How can I chunk grouped items?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm attempting to group items than chunk the items of each group. I came up with something that works, but I'm confused by `itemsGroup.FirstOrDefault()`. Why is there always a 1 item collection off the items group, and how might I change my query to avoid it?

```
var testItems = new[]
{
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-1" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-2" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-3" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-4" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-5" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-6" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-7" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-8" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-9" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-10" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-11" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-12" },
    new { ItemId = "A", Value = "A-13" },
    new { ItemId = "B", Value = "B-1" },
    new { ItemId = "B", Value = "B-2" },
    new { ItemId = "B", Value = "B-3" },
    new { ItemId = "B", Value = "B-4" },
    new { ItemId = "B", Value = "B-5" },
    new { ItemId = "B", Value = "B-6" },
    new { ItemId = "B", Value = "B-7" },
};


var groupedItems = testItems.GroupBy(ti => ti.ItemId)
    .GroupBy(o => o.Key, o => o.Chunk(5));

foreach (var itemsGroup in groupedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Group: {itemsGroup.Key}");

    var chunkNumber = 0;
    foreach (var chunk in itemsGroup.FirstOrDefault())
    {
        chunkNumber++;
        Console.WriteLine($"\tChunk: {chunkNumber}");
        foreach (var item in chunk)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t\tItem: {item.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Group: A
        Chunk: 1
                Item: A-1
                Item: A-2
                Item: A-3
                Item: A-4
                Item: A-5
        Chunk: 2
                Item: A-6
                Item: A-7
                Item: A-8
                Item: A-9
                Item: A-10
        Chunk: 3
                Item: A-11
                Item: A-12
                Item: A-13
Group: B
        Chunk: 1
                Item: B-1
                Item: B-2
                Item: B-3
                Item: B-4
                Item: B-5
        Chunk: 2
                Item: B-6
                Item: B-7
```

I'm in .NET 5 using the Chunk extension copied from .NET 6 here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5842db2c301cb1752ae854232a4fbae51d4a9ed0/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Chunk.cs

Comment: You are grouping twice, can't you just do a `GroupBy` and then a `Select(g => g.Chunk(5))`?

Comment: If you want to keep the key, you can return a tuple `(g.Key, g.Chunk(5))`